# Contact form 7 redirecting issue

Tags: wordpress

After submission, my contact form redirects to a URL followed by an unfamiliar code like #wpcf7-f1258-o1. but i used on_sent_ok: "my_redirect();" on additional heading.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The `on_sent_ok` method has been removed from Contact Form 7.

See: https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/

Try using a hook on the page where the contact form is located:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'cf7_redirect_script'); 
function cf7_redirect_script(){
    if(is_page('page-slug') { ?> // slug of the page which your contact form is on (can also be an ID)        
        <script>
            document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
                // put the desired redirect URL below
                location = 'http://yourdomain.com/thank-you';
            }, false );
        </script>  
    <?php } 
}
```